How to handle the uncontrollable CNT value, and how to connect it with CCR?
I am a beginner using the Nucleo-F334R8 with Keil and STM32CubeMX.
I want to read ADC data with DAC. The ADC is from a potentiometer, and I will read the DAC using an oscilloscope. I am using the program below so that when I run it, it will generate the frequency I need. I am using mapping to create the frequency range I want, with the frequency limits being from 10 Hz to 350 Hz, and I have achieved this according to the potentiometer setting I adjust. The biggest problem in my program is that when I run it and observe the CNT value, it counts up to the ARR value, and the oscilloscope displays a sinusoidal signal. However, when I adjust the signal back and forth, the signal disappears and only shows a straight line, with the CNT value becoming "VERY LARGE, EVEN INTO MILLIONS." I have to press the reset button on the Nucleo to display it again, but SOMETIMES IT DOESN'T WORK, and this is not a time/div issue since I have changed it, but rather a problem with CNT and ARR that I cannot control directly from the program. I have tried many things.
Because of this, I tried using a 32-bit ARR, but the CNT value became even larger and did not display the sinusoidal signal on the oscilloscope at all. When using a 16-bit ARR, the CNT displays stable values (which I think should produce a signal), but no signal appears on the oscilloscope, no matter how small. Then, my colleague suggested using CCR and preload, but I don't know where to place them. Since my colleague has left, I cannot ask him. Has anyone in this community experienced something similar? Please help me.
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */


//DAC
#define BUFFER_SIZE 225;
uint32_t Wave_LUT[225] = {
        2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,
        2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 
        2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,
      2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,
        2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 
        2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,2048, 2048, 2048, 2048, 2048,
    2048, 2149, 2250, 2350, 2450, 2549, 2646, 2742, 2837, 2929, 3020, 3108, 3193, 3275, 3355,
    3431, 3504, 3574, 3639, 3701, 3759, 3812, 3861, 3906, 3946, 3982, 4013, 4039, 4060, 4076,
    4087, 4094, 4095, 4091, 4082, 4069, 4050, 4026, 3998, 3965, 3927, 3884, 3837, 3786, 3730,
    3671, 3607, 3539, 3468, 3394, 3316, 3235, 3151, 3064, 2975, 2883, 2790, 2695, 2598, 2500,
    2400, 2300, 2199, 2098, 1997, 1896, 1795, 1695, 1595, 1497, 1400, 1305, 1212, 1120, 1031,
    944, 860, 779, 701, 627, 556, 488, 424, 365, 309, 258, 211, 168, 130, 97,
    69, 45, 26, 13, 4, 0, 1, 8, 19, 35, 56, 82, 113, 149, 189,
    234, 283, 336, 394, 456, 521, 591, 664, 740, 820, 902, 987, 1075, 1166, 1258,
    1353, 1449, 1546, 1645, 1745, 1845, 1946, 1950, 1965, 1975, 1990, 1999, 2010,2022, 2047
};
#define ARRAY_SIZE 4
uint32_t AD_RES[ARRAY_SIZE];

//MAPP
//OUTPUT = DAC
//INPUT = ADC
uint32_t input_start = 0;
uint32_t input_end = 4095;
uint32_t output_start = 9;
uint32_t output_end = 375;
uint32_t input;
uint32_t i;
uint32_t hasil;
uint32_t y;
uint32_t x;

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

DAC_HandleTypeDef hdac1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_dac1_ch1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

//ADC
uint32_t i = 0;
ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef ADC_CH_Cfg = {0};
uint32_t ADC_Channels[4] = {ADC_CHANNEL_6, ADC_CHANNEL_7, ADC_CHANNEL_8, ADC_CHANNEL_9};
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_DAC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

        
    //ADC
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_4);
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef ADC_CH_Cfg = {0};
    ADC_CH_Cfg.Rank =  ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  ADC_CH_Cfg.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;
    
    
    
    //DAC
    
    HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_1, Wave_LUT, 225, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);
    
    
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
            //ADC
            ADC_CH_Cfg.Channel = ADC_Channels[i];       
      HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &ADC_CH_Cfg); 
      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);                         
      if(HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK) 
                {
          AD_RES[i] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);  
        }
         HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
    }
            input = AD_RES[0]; 
            hasil = output_start + ((output_end - output_start)*(input - input_start))/(input_end - input_start);
            __HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim2, hasil);
            __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1, hasil); 
            y = hasil;
            x = input;
    }
        
    HAL_Delay(500);
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV16;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC12;
  PeriphClkInit.Adc12ClockSelection = RCC_ADC12PLLCLK_DIV1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_MultiModeTypeDef multimode = {0};
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */

  /** Common config
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure the ADC multi-mode
  */
  multimode.Mode = ADC_MODE_INDEPENDENT;
  if (HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeConfigChannel(&hadc1, &multimode) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_7CYCLES_5;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief DAC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 0 */

  DAC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 1 */

  /** DAC Initialization
  */
  hdac1.Instance = DAC1;
  if (HAL_DAC_Init(&hdac1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** DAC channel OUT1 config
  */
  sConfig.DAC_Trigger = DAC_TRIGGER_T2_TRGO;
  sConfig.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OUTPUTBUFFER_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel(&hdac1, &sConfig, DAC_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 10;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 0;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */
    
//    // Konfigurasi master
//    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
//    sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
//    HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig);
    
  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

Because of this, I tried using a 32-bit ARR, but the CNT value became even larger and did not display the sinusoidal signal on the oscilloscope at all. When using a 16-bit ARR, the CNT displays stable values (which I think should produce a signal), but no signal appears on the oscilloscope, no matter how small. Then, my colleague suggested using CCR and preload, but I don't know where to place them. Since my colleague has left, I cannot ask him. Has anyone in this community experienced something similar? Please help me.

This question is similar to: DAC freq LOST and signal in osciloscop is unstable, used STM32 NUCLEOF334R8. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try changing TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE to TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE If you change ARR to a value lower than CNT, the timer will keep counting untill overflow. With ARR preload enabled, it's new value is taken in account only on the next overflow
